# Conky widgets won't render some of their graphics

Tags: gnome, graphics, conky

OS: Arch

Desktop: gnome

Conky version: 1.10.8-2 + conky-manager-2.4-2

Widgets used: conky seamod (conky_manager default), [conky rings](https://trollpunny.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Rings-Revamped-591137228)

### The problem:

when using one of those widgets a very spesific circle graphic seems to not appear

conky logs: [seamod](https://pastebin.com/ZE3PRngn), [rings](https://pastebin.com/yejU62DU)

screenshot of conky rings in real time:
[image: conky rings screenshot]

how conky seamod should look (right) how seamod render on my computer (left)
[image: conky seamod screenshot]

### Update (1):

Due to a comment i have installed the package cairo, the resault is still the same, new logs: [rings](https://pastebin.com/uiZJ97kS), [seamod](https://pastebin.com/A8cjrwUC),

### Update (2):

I have found out that the problem lays in the "cairo" package that for some reason wont install on arch linux, cairo is a graphic package and probably the source of the problem. If any one can help please write

Comment: Your logs say that *cairo* was not found. This is the library used to draw the graphics. Install the cairo arch package and try again.

Comment: I have installed cairo, new logs added, its still the  same...

Comment: I dont use arch linux, but I tried the rings code on fedora and it was ok, so I setup an arch linux on a virtual machine and tried after installing conky and cairo, and got the same error as you. Compared with fedora there seem to be some libraries missing, such as `/usr/lib64/conky/libcairo.so`. I think you will need to ask for help on an arch linux forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems contributer *Paramvir Likhari* has added to the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/) repository a suitable source package that you can build to have conky with cairo and lua 5.3.  I did the following on a qemu virtual machine installation of arch linux, and was able to run conky and see the rings drawn after the initial 10 seconds or so (after editing `clock_rings.lua` for only 1 cpu for my VM).

I followed the standard instructions on building a package, so I will not repeat them. The only thing to know is which source package(s) to build, and that is `conky-cairo`. It failed to build until I first also built dependency `tolua++_5.3`, and then failed to build until I removed the need for Xinerama. No doubt there are ways to build with this option too. Here are the commands I ran

```
sudo pacman -S --needed base-devel
curl -O https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.gz
zgrep conky packages.gz
# choose conky-cairo
sudo pacman -S git
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/conky-cairo.git
cd conky-cairo/
# read the file PKGBUILD for info and potential malware
makepkg -si PKGBUILD 
# gave me error: target not found: tolua++_5.3
cd ..
zgrep tolua packages.gz
# choose tolua++_5.3
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/tolua++_5.3.git
cd tolua++_5.3
# read the file PKGBUILD for info and potential malware
makepkg -si PKGBUILD 
cd ..
cd conky-cairo
makepkg -s PKGBUILD 
# gave me a CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
# Xinerama_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
# I removed the option with:
sed -i src/conky-1.10.7/CMakeCache.txt -e '/BUILD_XINERAMA/s/ON/OFF/'
makepkg -si PKGBUILD 
cd ../Conky/
conky -c rings
```

It will ask you if it can remove any existing conky package in order to install the new one.

---

This is the resulting script:

```
sudo pacman -S --needed base-devel
sudo pacman -S git
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/tolua++_5.3.git
(cd tolua++_5.3 && makepkg -si PKGBUILD)
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/conky-cairo.git
(cd conky-cairo/ && makepkg -si PKGBUILD)
cd conky-cairo
sed -i src/conky-1.10.7/CMakeCache.txt -e '/BUILD_XINERAMA/s/ON/OFF/'
makepkg -si PKGBUILD 
cd ..
```

Comment: That worked for me, you could refine the suggested code so it'll contain a fully working paste?

Comment: The code should work as-is, but I added a shortened version which bypasses the error stages.